# PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "USING"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm having trouble migrating my table with Rails. When I run rake db:migrate I get this error.

## Error

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USING"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "assignments" ADD "frequency" integer USING CAST...
```

### Migration

```
class AddBackFrequeny < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :assignments, :frequency, 'integer USING CAST(frequency AS integer)'
  end
end
```

I just changed my database to postgresql. maybe somethings there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`USING` is only valid when you alter the `DATA TYPE`, not when you merely add a column. From `\h ALTER`

```
ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name [ SET DATA ] TYPE data_type [ COLLATE collation ] [ USING expression ]
ADD [ COLUMN ] [ IF NOT EXISTS ] column_name data_type [ COLLATE collation ] [ column_constraint [ ... ] ]
```